# При нажатии на иконку расширения Chrome страница обновляется

Tags: сокет, google-chrome

Страница background.html содержит html страницу чата, с подгрузкой в него необходимых js, с помощью которых происходит подключение к сокет серверу.

Дело в том, что при каждом клике на иконку происходит переподключение.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как настроить background.js, чтобы при нажатии на иконку расширения фоновая страница не загружалась снова, а открывалась на том же месте?

manifest.js

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Socket Chat",
    "version": "1.34",
    "options_page": "options.html",

    "icons": {
        "128": "images/icon.png"
      },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "128": "images/icon128.png"
        },
        "default_popup": "background.html",
    },

    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "background"
    ],

    "background": {
        "page": "background.html",
        "persistent": true
    },

    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"

}
```

Comment: иконка какого расширения?

Comment: @ValeriuVodnicear я создаю расширение, которое открывает всплывающее окно, загружающее страницу с чатом

Comment: Вероятно имеет место быть ошибка в JS. Покажите код, пожалуйста.